# What could be causing water to leak out of the overflow hole from the bottom of a sink?

Tags: plumbing

I have installed a new sink (A St. Thomas Creations Antiqua Petite Oval Self-Rimming Lavatory Sink with Overflow). After the water has been running for a while, water starts to leak out of the overflow hole from the bottom of the sink.  There is no leakage around the stopper or the drain pipe connections.  What could be causing this problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: I'm confused. Normally the "overflow hole" just runs overflow back into the drain. Either you've got something hooked up weirdly (photo might help), or you're describing it oddly (photo might help), or you've got a damaged sample (photo might help)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a drain pipe is clogged. The overflow hole is for overflow water to run into the drain pipe. If the water coming out of the overflow hole goes down the drain then I agree with the first poster, something is to hooked up incorrectly. If the water accumulates in the sink with the pop up open, then the drain is plugged.